# SmtpClient asp net core 3.0 with IEmailSender work on Windows but not On Linux

Tags: c#, linux, windows, asp.net-core

I have the following situation. I am migrating my .Net MVC to net core 3.0 MVC for my local raspbery pi. I am building my app on the Windows machine where IEmailSender middlewere with SmtpClient is working but on Linux I have the following exception

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: <my@gmail.com> No such user here
```

I have tried to send the mail from windows and Linux without the `IEmailSender` and its working fine but with `IEmailSender` in place I have that error.

The reason to use `IEmailSender` is because i don't want to scaffold the `Identity` that is why I use it in my controllers.

```cs
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSenderCore>(i =>
    new EmailSenderCore(

       //Configuration["Gmail"]
       Configuration["RibelleMail"]
   ));
```

My class implementation

```cs
public class EmailSenderCore : IEmailSender
{
    private string mailPass;

    public EmailSenderCore(string password)
    {
        mailPass = password;
    }

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string emailTo, string subject, string message)
    {
        //return Gmail(mailPass, subject, message, emailTo);
        return Ribelle(mailPass, subject, message, emailTo);
    }

    public Task Ribelle(string mailPass, string subject, string message, string emailTo)
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("my@email") { };
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailTo);
        MailAddress carbonCopy = new MailAddress("my@cc") { };

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(from,to)
        {
            From = from,
            Subject = subject,
            Body = message,  
        };

        mailMessage.CC.Add(carbonCopy);

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.host", 25)
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mailUser", mailPass),
            EnableSsl = false
        };

        // Send it...         
        return smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: probably nothing to do with it, but it could: you have a typing error, the exception lists the emailadress as: my@gmail.com but the mailadress registers as my@email

Comment: I just type them for example in real scenario they match. For me is IEmailSender because with out my mails going out withou troblem and is only on Linux Windows is fine.

Comment: On Linux make sure the speiling is correct. On Windows big and small letters dont matter, unlike on Linux